# null is not an object ( evaluating 'NativeUnimoduleProxy.viewManagersNames')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image: a busy cat]
Hi, I am having this issue in android. I am using react-native: 0.59.8,
@unimodules/core: ^4.0.0,
@unimodules/react-native-adapter: ^4.0.0

Comment: Same issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 6):

You may be going about installing Unimodules the wrong way. Try following the guide [here on the `react-native-unimodules` page instead](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/). After following it meticulously I was able to get `expo-camera` working in a bare `react-native` project just moments after commenting on your question.

Make sure that you *closely* compare your own `ios/` files with the ones linked in the guide.

Comment: Glad it could help! RN can be messy sometimes.